# How to get the parameter after question mark in react router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-v4

In react in my routes, I have mapped the components like

```
<Route path="/search/:id" component={Search}/>
```

So, i am expecting a URL like search/jeans, or search/shirts . But on some occasions i am getting a URL pattern like

```
/search/?text=shirts
```

Which i am not able to handle. Please suggest how can i proceed with this. I want to get the value of "shirts" from that URL. How to get make the existing route to handle this this different URL ?

Comment: You [cannot](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4410) anymore. See explantation below.

Answer (score 1):

The ability to parse query strings was [taken out of V4](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4410) unfortunately. You can choose which method to use.
3rd party package:

```
const queryString = require('query-string');

const parsed = queryString.parse(props.location.search);
```

Or use a built in:

```
const params = new URLSearchParams(props.location.search);

const foo = params.get('foo'); // bar
```

and for URLSearchParams, there is also a [polyfill](https://github.com/WebReflection/url-search-params) for compatibility.